# Python 3: How to evaluate the Adam Gradient in Tensor Flow 2.0? I would like to replace my implementation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I have the following code that is working well. However, I strongly believe that the Tensorflow 2.0 implementation of the Adam Gradient is more efficient than my naive implementation.
How can I replace the evaluation of the Adam Gradient by the Tensorflow 2.0 implementation?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def linearModelGenerator(numberSamples):
    x = tf.random.normal(shape=(numberSamples,))
    y = 3*tf.ones(shape=(numberSamples,)) + tf.constant(5.0) * x +  tf.random.normal(shape=(numberSamples,),stddev=0.01)
    return x,y

class Adam:
    def __init__(self,shapes,lr=0.001,beta1=0.9,beta2=0.999,epsilon=1e-07):
        self.lr=lr
        self.beta1=beta1
        self.beta2=beta2
        self.epsilon=epsilon
        self.shapes=shapes
        self.m=np.shape(shapes)[0]
        self.listM=[]
        self.listV=[]
        self.t=0
        for i in range(self.m):
            if(np.isscalar(shapes[i])):
                self.listM.append(0)#append(tf.zeros(shapes[i]))
                self.listV.append(0)#append(tf.zeros(shapes[i]))
            else:
                self.append(tf.zeros(shapes[i]))
                self.append(tf.zeros(shapes[i]))

    def evalGradient(self,*args):
        adamGrad=[]
        self.t=self.t+1
        for i in range(self.m):
            grad=args[i]
            self.listM[i]=self.beta1*self.listM[i]+(1-self.beta1)*grad
            self.listV[i]=self.beta2*self.listV[i]+(1-self.beta2)*(grad*grad)
            hatM=self.listM[i]/(1-(self.beta1)**self.t)
            hatV=self.listV[i]/(1-(self.beta2)**self.t)
            adamGrad.append(hatM/(tf.math.sqrt(hatV)+(tf.ones(np.shape(hatV))*self.epsilon)))
        return adamGrad




class LinearModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.weight = tf.Variable(-1.0)
        self.bias = tf.Variable(-1.0)
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.weight * x + self.bias

def loss(y, pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - pred))


def trainAdam(linear_model,adam, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        current_loss = loss(y, linear_model(x))
    gradWeight, gradBias = t.gradient(current_loss, [linear_model.weight, linear_model.bias])
    gradAdamList=adam.evalGradient(gradWeight,gradBias)
    gradAdamWeight=gradAdamList[0]
    gradAdamBias=gradAdamList[1]
    linear_model.weight.assign_sub(adam.lr * gradAdamWeight)
    linear_model.bias.assign_sub(adam.lr * gradAdamBias)        


if __name__=="__main__":
    numberSamples=100
    x,y=linearModelGenerator(numberSamples)
    linear_model = LinearModel()
    epochs = 1000
    shapes=[]
    shapes.append(1)
    shapes.append(1)
    adam=Adam(shapes,lr=0.1)
    for epoch_count in range(epochs):
         real_loss = loss(y, linear_model(x))
         trainAdam(linear_model,adam, x, y)

         print('w',linear_model.weight.numpy())

         print('bias',linear_model.bias.numpy())

         print('real_loss',real_loss.numpy())
```

I would like to keep the general structure of the code, but to replace the Adam Gradient Implementation.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: why can't you just use the built-in `tf.optimizers.Adam()` directly? It works with GradientTape. It won't have the `evalGradient()` method of course, but you can use its `apply_gradient()` method.

Comment: I did not find out how to do that! Can I realy use it with GradientTape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in optimizers in TensorFlow 2 can not only be used with `tf.keras.Model.fit()`, but also with `tf.GradientTape()`. With the latter, you can just call its `apply_gradients()` method directly. The optimizer object will keep track of the accumulators and running moments internally. Roughly, your code can be modified as follows:

```py
adam = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)

def trainAdam(linear_model,adam, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as t:
        current_loss = loss(y, linear_model(x))
    gradWeight, gradBias = t.gradient(current_loss, [linear_model.weight, linear_model.bias])
    adam.apply_gradients(zip([gradWeight, gradBias], [linear_model.weight, linear_model.bias]))
```

Comment: Thank you! But I am not sure that I really understand. What variable shoud I use to update the weights? The documentation says that apply_gradients "Returns:       An `Operation` that applies the specified gradients, but what does it mean. " In this context, who are gradAdamWeight and 
    gradAdamBias?

Comment: `apply_gradients()` will update the weights, which are `[linear_model.weight, linear_model.bias]` in this case.